# How to swap parameters in this debug case with php 7.4? – join()

Tags: php, join

I'm updating an older website with a newer version of kirby (2.2.3 to 2.5.14) and php (5.6. to 7.4) and I'm getting this debug. I'm quite new to php and don't know how it should be written correctly with newer version of php. I checked existing questions/answers and I tried swapping parameters but didn't succeed yet. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

```
anchors:[<?php echo "'" . join($pages->visible()->pluck('uri'), "','") . "'" ; ?>],
```

[debug screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdp0p.png)

Comment: *I tried swapping parameters but didn't succeed yet* - can you show what you have tried?  (this is virtually the same as the previous question which was closed as a duplicate, so if there is a problem implementing the suggested solution it helps to show what you have tried).

Comment: The function PHP uses here are echo and join. This looks ok.. Could you include a error message?

Comment: the "implode" code of @user126587 worked! problem solved :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use implode like this -

```
echo "'" . implode("','", $pages->visible()->pluck('uri')) . "'" ;
```

Just swap the params.

Look for the docs on the web site [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php), make sure you use some sort of code inspection tool as a first step. Then check if you have any breaking changes and fix that. Then you check the new features for the next version and do the same up to the version you are on.

Comment: using your suggested "implode" code works! thanks a lot, also for the docs website link!